# Limit images from loading on a mobile version of a site

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm currently building a mobile version of a site.

Not a separate domain (mobile.example.com) but a respnosive approach (using media queries to load certain CSS for screen size)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to reduce the "page size".

The desktop version of my site includes a jquery slider plugin, which slides through five relatively large, high res images.  My mobile side does not include that.  However, those images continue to be loaded when the mobile version is built.

I've  set their display property to none, but this still loads the images.

So how can I, whether through javascript or another type of media query, specify what files should and should not be loaded?

Comment: If your pages are dynamically generated you could do it depending on the user agent string.  This isn't the best way to do it though.

Comment: No that's why i use a media query - basically if the screen resolution is less than 480, I load a certain style sheet.  I just dont know how to not load other images on the page.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is to only supply the image tag and/or src path via JavaScript depending on the media device.  This, of course, poses a whole new set of problems for users w/o JS.  I think serving up two separate sets of pages may be your only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great article at SmashingMagazine.com "[Responsive Web Design Techniques, Tools and Design Strategies](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/22/responsive-web-design-techniques-tools-and-design-strategies/)" that rounds up many of the ways developers have tried to tackle this issue.

That said, there is not one "best practice" yet.